# How to avoid plotting observations ON the plot lines in ggplot2 (with geom_point)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my ggplot2-plot, there are around 150 observations plotted along a CATEGORICAL variable in the x-axis (see picture below). However, the observations closest to the y-axes are plotted onto the line of the plot, and this I want to avoid (see arrows in the picture).

How do I do that?

(If the x-axis was continuous, I could have set the limits manually, but I don't see how that's possible with categorical variables ...)

Here's how the plot looks as for now:

[image: (I want more space around the points marked with yellow arrows)]

Comment: Maybe with ```expand = c(0, 0)``` in the ```scale``` argument?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for putting me on the right track, K. Maya :-) I googled my way to the following solution: Adding this to my plot command fixed my problem (though I'm not 100 % sure how ...):

```
scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(add = 2))
```

Here's how the plot looks with the above addition:

[image]